# How can I adjust the space between sections in a grouped Table View?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, grouped-table

I have a tableview that is basically four sections in length, designed for user input.  I am not using headers or footers as of now.

Section 0 has 4 rows.
Section 1 has 2 rows.
Section 2 has 1 row.
Section 3 has 1 row.

I want to have section 2 and 3 a little closer together and sections 0 and 1 a little closer together - basically configuring the space in between cells.

I have searched far and wide and have found nothing specific on how to do this.  Suggestions?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 3):

Handle

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

More info here:

[UITableView Not Respecting heightForHeaderInSection/heightForFooterInSection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386826/uitableview-not-respecting-heightforheaderinsection-heightforfooterinsection)

Comment: I tried the above handle, without success.  I will need to read through that article link you provided and report back.  Thank you.

Comment: There's a minimum.  Also there's a way to put your own views in the header.

Answer (score 2):

If your tableview is set to Grouped, and not Plain, you can use the default invisible footers as padding. This way you can leave your headers looking good (and not have a giant gap above the first section)

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
      if section == 0 || section == 2 {
        return 20
      } else {
        return 40
      }
  }
```

Just FYI, if you return 0 it will ignore it and go with the default amount. To completely hide the footer, set it to 0.0001 or something