# Hide section header in UITabllView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7.1

I'd like to hide the head of the first section in a UITableView. Therefore, I set the height to 0 in the following function. But the Header is still shown? What's wrong? If I set it to e.g. 1 I see a small line on top of the table. Any ideas?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 18;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386826/uitableview-not-respecting-heightforheaderinsection-heightforfooterinsection

Comment: Describes the same issue but I found a better solution (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding the following line of code in the viewDidLoad() method. Additionally set the height in the heightForHeaderInSection to 1.0f (method see above).

```
// Correct position because section header height will be set to 1 in order to hide it.
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0);
```

Comment: Neat! I'll remember this one. :)