# What is the UITableView separator color in iOS 7?

Tags: uitableview, ios7, colors

What is the color that Apple uses for the separators in a grouped UITableView?

Is there a constant or some way I can access this programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 28):

The inspector tool in the Apple's color picker, reports the color as follows:

- Hex: `#c8c7cc`
- RGB (255): `200, 199, 204`
- RGB (1.0): `0.783922, 0.780392, 0.8`

You can access this value programmatically by accessing the table view's [separatorColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/separatorColor) property.

```
UIColor *separatorColor = self.tableView.separatorColor;
// [separatorColor description] = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.783922 0.780392 0.8 1
```

Comment: For iOS8 color is `D1D1D4`

Comment: Is this color also available in one of the palettes of Interface Builder?

Comment: @JanMisker you can add custom colors to Interface builder color palette

Comment: UIColor.grayColor() seems to be the closest out-of-the box preset available. iOS8

Comment: Is this sRGB color codes? Also the height of the separator is 0.5px