# UITableView contentSize too big by 10pt (iOS 10 only!)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having a strange issue. I have a `UITableView` set like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 210.0
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if drawerState == .closed {
        return 0
    }
    return 1
}
```

Initially the `drawerState` is `.closed` so the `contentSize` is `210`. I then hit a button that changes the state and prints the new content size like so:

```
drawerState = .assessmentOpen
print("old content size is \(tableView.contentSize.height)")
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)], with: .none)
print("new content size is \(self.tableView.contentSize.height)")
```

The result I get is:

```
old content size is 210.0
new content size is 420.0
```

The new content size is 10pt more than it should be (new content size should be 410). Where does this excess height come from? Oddly enough if I print the value again after a delay it is correct. I have tried all combinations of `layoutIfNeeded` and using `DispatchQueue.main.async` the value is always 10pt more than it should be. What am I doing wrong? NOTE: It only behaves like this on iOS10, iOS11 there are no issues.

Comment: Could you try to cover `insertRows(at:,with:) ` with `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdated()` methods?

Comment: try this- self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false in viewDidLoad and check

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko tried this and no luck. Note I only see this bug on iOS10.

Comment: @vivekDas Tried this, Still doesn't work. Note I only see this bug on iOS10

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `.grouped`-styled `UITableView` then the footer of each section has a default height which is not zero. So to fix that add this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}
```

If you return just `0`. It falls back to the default value. Technically the `CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude` is pretty much like a `0`. But if you compare it a `0` is smaller than `CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude`.

Comment: Please see updated question. I only have an issue on iOS10. iOS11 the contentSize is correct. Added your code and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting height of footer to `zero` and returning `nil` for footer view?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Yeah I see it as well, in iOS 10 if i return return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude or 0.1 for example for height all works, check this answer maybe it can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386826/uitableview-not-respecting-heightforheaderinsection-heightforfooterinsection

Comment: I get new content size is 420.000001 if I use 0.000001 for the header size on iOS10, it's still 10 pts too big.

Comment: I get this on iOS 10.3.3 on an iPad `old content size is 210.0` 
`new content size is 410.0`

Comment: This with a header?

Comment: Same result on iPhone 6 and iPad running 10.3.3